# Migration from Sybase to a different platform

Tags: migration, sybase

How feasible it is move the Sybase database to a different more popular platform such SQL Server or any other. Which one is preferred? Is it feasible in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How feasible it is move the Sybase database to a different more popular platform such SQL Server or any other.
>
> Is it feasible in the first place?

Very feasible and supported by the vendors (e.g. Microsoft in-case of SQL Server). I have done plenty of SybaseASE to SQL Server migrations.

Best is to use [SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA)](https://web.archive.org/web/20161003141014/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43691) for migration.

Refer to :

- [Migrating from Sybase ASE to SQL Server – How to use SSMA for Sybase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ssma/migrating-from-sybase-ase-to-sql-server-how-to-use-ssma-for-sybase)
- [SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) Team's Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151208173610/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ssma/p/sybase.aspx)

> Which one is preferred?

Its up to your business what RDBMS they want to use. We are a Microsoft shop running majority of our software on Microsoft stack and so we move our Sybase Clients to SQL Server.

*If you have any specific step that you find hard to proceed further, let me know and I will help you out, but above links will give you  a good start.*

Comment: Thanks!! Can you also tell what other platforms are feasible for migration besides SQL server? Just for info.!

Comment: @tesla747 Mostly all the major database vendors like Oracle, Microsoft, DB2 support conversion to their platform. As I said, you need to evaluate your business requirements and then make a decision what  suits your business.